# Using configparser for text read from URL using urllib2

Tags: python, configparser

I have to read a txt ini file  from my browser. [this is required]

```
res = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
inifile = res.read()
```

Then I want to basically use this the same way as I would have read any txt file.

```
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.read( inifile )
```

But now looks like I can't use it as this is actually a string now

Can anybody suggest a way around?

Answer (score 1):

You want [`configparser.readfp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.readfp) -- Presumably, you might even be able to get away with:

```
res = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
config = ConfgiParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.readfp(res)
```

assuming that `urllib2.urlopen` returns an object that is sufficiently file-like (i.e. it has a `readline` method).  For easier debugging, you could do:

```
config.readfp(res, URL)
```

If you have to read it the data from a string, you could pack the whole thing into a `io.StringIO` (or `StringIO.StringIO`) buffer and read from that:

```
import io

res = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
inifile_text = res.read()

inifile = io.StringIO(inifile_text)
inifile.seek(0)
config.readfp(inifile)
```